# unable to render image in pdf :grails

Tags: java, pdf, grails

below is my code-

```
    ApplicationTagLib applicationTagLib = new ApplicationTagLib()
    String html = applicationTagLib.include(controller: 'survey', action: 'pdf', params: [id: id])
    html = html.replaceAll('&', '&amp;')
    html = html.replaceAll('&amp;#', '&#')
    html = html.replaceAll('&nbsp;', ' ')

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/"
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(content);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report.pdf")
    response.setContentType("application/pdf")
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    out.close()
```

In pdf action of survey Contrller-

```
render(view: 'download')
```

download.gsp

```
<g:img dir="assets/common" file="pointer.jpg"/>
<img src="assets/common/pin.png"/>
```

pdf we are getting have all data except these image

Note-while I am hitting direct pdf action of survey contrller this is renderring image fine.[`localhost:8080/survey/pdf`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating PDF the relative `path/source` does not work for static resources. You have to provide the absolute `path/source` for them.

You should not hard code your `baseUrl`. You can inject the `grailsLinkGenerator` bean then the `baseUrl` will be available at `grailsLinkGenerator.serverBaseURL`.

So you can get the `baseUrl` in controller through `grailsLinkGenerator` and then pass it through `model` to your view. Then your `img` tag can look like following

```
    <img src="${baseUrl}/assets/common/pin.png"/>
```